# HTML in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, html-parsing

I am making a silverlight interface for a discussion board. The boards web interface allows the usual HTML tags like i,a,img,b,u. So now I need to be able to display that in Silverlight.
This: http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/rich_textblock.aspx seemed like exactly what I need except that it hardly displays anything right. Every HTML(i've made sure it's valid with HTMLAgility) string I give it either makes the whole SL app go white, or the block displays all the text on top of each other. Occasionally(with a few VERY simply strings), it will display right.

This needs to work OOB and in, and I cannot use the WebBrowser control as I would need hundreds of instances at a time and it gets slow(tried it OOB).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2010/09/15/Displaying-HTML-in-Silverlight.aspx

Maybe it can serve your needs better.

Comment: Nice :). I had used the one this is based on, which didn't work. But this does! For anyone reading this, to make it work nicely I still needed to pass everything through HTMLAgility to make sure it was fixed, then I also replaced the img creation to make it use the ImageTools library so as to allow animated gifs inline too.

Answer (score 1):

Some others

http://www.isosoft.org/taoffi/post/Html-Content-Viewer-for-Silverlight.aspx
http://blog.gfader.com/2010/05/silverlight-showing-html-content-inside.html
http://www.divelements.co.uk/silverlight/tools.aspx

Component one and Telerik both have silverlight html controls at a cost.
http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/htmlplaceholder.aspx
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/HtmlHostSilverlight/

Comment: Thanks - but in this case those would not work because they are based off floating a div over the SL app which is not possible in OOB.