# Display HTML in a silverlight application

Tags: c#, .net, html, silverlight, xaml

I need to display HTML in my silverlight application and cannot find a way of doing it. I cannot use the web browser control as it needs to be able to run in or out of a browser.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this, because all I can think of doing at the moment is running replace methods on the text to just replace the tags with C# equivalents eg(`<br />` to `\n`).

Comment: I'm assuming the reason you need to be able to run this out of browser is that you need to use elevated permissions for something. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to check if the application is running inside the browser and change the means of display accordingly.  If running inside the browser, I overlay the application with an IFrame, as I describe in this article: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-Silverlight-Line-Of-Business-Application-Part-6.aspx.  Otherwise, I use the WebBrowser control.  I have a control which does this all for you in the source code that accompanies my book, which is downloadable from the Apress website here: http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4638.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(VS.95).aspx).

**Edit** I'm am actually now unsure if you'll still have access to javascript if you're running this OOB. I'm going to look into this some more and will further update. I'll still leave the answer up though for reference.

**Second Edit** Here is what I've found. HTML Bridge is disabled when you run silverlight out of browser. This disables access to the HTML DOM as well as Javascript. However, according to a comment on [this site](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-s-new-out-of-browser-applications.aspx):

> HTML Bridge is not available when you first install a OOB app. But you CAN force it if you modify the index.html in the folder where the app is installed just adding the enablehtmlaccess parameter.
>
> It works!
>
> You can even create dynamic HTML elements using the well-known methods of the HtmlPage class.  You can even open a new browser window with the Navigate() method and its "_blank" parameter.

Keep in mind this information was posted about SL 3. Its possible that this may have changed, but I doubt it. So it seems that what you may want to do is build a script into the startup of your SL app that detects whether or not your app is running out of browser. If it is then you may want to have some script to call that can modify this file for you.

Answer (score 0):

There recently was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293783/html-in-silverlight).

I posted a link there to an implementation that parses and displays HTML inline in Silverlight. Of course, it will work only with simple HTML, but maybe you can expand it to your needs.